# Azure DNS server keep connecting to virtual machine endpoints

Tags: .net, azure, dns

I am running a custom server (C# console application) on a Windows Azure virtual machine.
The server is listening on a custom high port (between 10000 to 11000). For the server to accept connections from the outside I am opening the port on the local firewall and setting up an endpoint to that port using the Azure management console.

When all done, I am starting to get connection to the server from Azure DNS server (the same as in ipconfig for my machine).
The endpoint is not load-balanced and it is a stand alone virtual machine.

The connections stay open and never getting closed. A new connection is established every 3-5 seconds. This issue is causing my server to crash.

Comment: Can you give more tech details?

Comment: @Fabrizio The Virtual machine is hosted on Azure running Windows 2012 server. My application  is listening on port 10800. As soon as I run my app I get incoming connections from Azure DNS server (168.63.129.16). no data transfers, only SYN-ACK. Happens only after both endpoint (azure management console) and local firewall set to allow connections on that port.

Comment: Are you sure the connections come from 168.63.129.16? It's very strange. Try a NETSTAT -N from the command line. If you are sure, open a support ticket and ask Miscrosoft why they are calling you on that port.

Comment: I am sure. Using netstat i got this IP. And it's not that port, it's any port. When I change the port number the connections are coming to the new one. The basic support of azure is for pricing only, the technical one requires extra payment.

Comment: Can you copy & paste a NETSTAT -N ?

Comment: Exactly the same is happening to me! Additionally to your description, the connection from outside is very unstable. Sometimes I can connect, and most of the time not, with no apparent reason. Unfortunately I have no solution.

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue as well. If I look in netstat, I even see that the DNS server has established a connection to IIS, but it has not established a connection to RDP, which is configured in the azure management console the same way. Is there a way to handle this in code to prevent the DNS server from continually opening connections?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Late answer, but for the benefit of anyone arriving here from a search engine, see answer from Craig Landis at this link:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/silverlight/en-US/04589d2d-4acb-4f86-a2d0-957dc2a73a4f/endpoints-not-working-dns-scans-them

In summary, there was a change recently so that when you create an endpoint in the portal, it is automatically load balanced and regularly "probed" to check if the endpoint is alive. At the time of writing, the portal will still display the endpoint status as 'not load balanced'. You have to use the Azure CLI tool or PowerShell to recreate the endpoint without load balancing - it cannot be done from the portal.

It is the load balancer that tries to probe the endpoint every 15 seconds, and can take the endpoint out of service if it doesn't get the response it expects. This is very likely to happen if you have custom protocols / ports that aren't permanently listening, etc.